# Размер\разрешение экрана

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть 2д картинка, как сделать так чтобы на разных размерах/расширениях экрана все выглядело одинаково, а не так как сейчас. На одном видео 70% картинки, на другом 80% и т.д. Как сделать чтобы было видно все 100% всегда не зависимо от размерах/расширениях экрана.
Как видно на скринах некоторая область скрыта. Как это исправить?

[image: 480*320]
[image: 1024*600]

Comment: У вас на скринах узкий и широкий форматы. Одинаково оно не может выглядеть в принципе. Вы можете,например, имитировать широкий формат подогнав ширину под разрешение узкого.Как вариант, можно нарисовать под картой стол, который не жалко обрезать, но и выглядеть он будет лучше, чем чёрная область )
Вот [картинка](https://images1.popmeh.ru/upload/img_cache/e7d/e7df314f3dacb9b7f5bb874c7657fae2_fitted_800x600.jpg) с вариантами решения вашей проблемы. Какой вам нужен?

Comment: Мне нужно вариант норме 4 и так чтобы выглядело на всех экранах и расширениях, чтоб на 1280*720 не пропало 10% изображения